# Trying to receive input and display if it's correct or incorrect using ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android

```
**activity_main xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.hynes.equations.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please select what type of equation to solve"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<Button
    android:text="Check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginRight="230dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="230dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginRight="170dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="170dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText2" />

<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radio_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

<RadioButton
    android:text="Addition"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:id="@+id/addition"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:text="Subtraction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/subtraction"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:text="Division"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/division"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:text="Multiplication"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/multiplication"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

`

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;`
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int x;
private int y;
public int a;
public int b;
Random random = new Random();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view){
    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    int btnID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        switch(btnID){
            case R.id.addition:
                x = random.nextInt(100);
                y = random.nextInt(100);
                display.setText(x + "+" + y + "=");
                break;
            case R.id.subtraction:
                x = random.nextInt(100);
                y = random.nextInt(100);
                display.setText(x + "-" + y + "=");
                break;
            case R.id.division:
                y = random.nextInt(5);
                x = y*2;
                display.setText(x + "/" + y + "=");
                break;
             case R.id.multiplication:
            x = random.nextInt(10);
            y = random.nextInt(10);
            display.setText(x + "*" + y + "=");
            break;
    }

 public void onClickCheck(View view){

    TextView result = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    EditText ans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    int btnID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    if(boolean(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.addition)) ){
        int key = x+y;
        int try = 0;
        while(!ans.equals(key)){
            try = try + 1;
            if(try ==0){
                result.setText("Incorrect, try again!");
                try++
            }else if (try>2){
                    result.setText("Incorrect, the answer is : " + key);
            }
        if(ans.equals(key)){
            result.setText("You are correct !");
        }
        }
    }

}
}

}
 }
```

This is a android studio app that's suppose to randomly generate a math equation upon creation which I've done. There's addition, subtraction, division, and multiplication. My random equation generator works perfectly. But I'm stuck at my onClickCheck method which i want to get the user's answer/input and check to see if it's correct or incorrect and display a message accordingly. My onClick method is wrong but it's a start. I don't know what methods i need to get my code to accept inputs properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't assigning an OnClickListener to the button.

You need to put:(in onCreate)

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button.setOnClickListener(onClickCheck);
```

or

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClickCheck(view);
            }
        });
```

Same for the radio button.

Comment: Okay, and what about the onclickCheck method. How does that syntax playout